# Silverlight Out of Browser Application making Http Requests through a proxy

Tags: silverlight, proxy, out-of-browser

When running Silverlight 3.0 in OOB mode, you don't have to worry about any proxy authentication as the browser normally takes care of this.

If I've installed a Silverlight app in OOB mode, is there any way to authenticate against a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like it is possible in SL3

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help:

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-beta-videos/network-authentication-trusted-network-access/

Comment: Thanks but this is for Silverlight 4.0 and I'm trying to do this in 3.0.